# Programming paradigm quiz

Tags: python, python-3.x, quiz

I have this code, which isn't for the moment optimized:

```
def capture_inputs(cleaner):
    return cleaner(input("What are valid programming paradigms?").split(","))

def clean_input(user_input):
    result = []
    for paradigm in user_input:
        result.append(paradigm.strip())
    return result

def count_valid_programming_paradigms(paradigms):
    valid_paradigms  = {"imperative","functional","object-oriented","logical","declarative"}
    given_paradigms = set(paradigms)
    return len(valid_paradigms & given_paradigms)

def report_result(user_input, counter):
    valid_paradigms_count = counter(user_input)
    if counter(user_input) > 0:
        print("You found {} valid paradigms".format(valid_paradigms_count))
    else:
        print("You did not find any valid paradigm")
        
report_result(capture_inputs(clean_input),count_valid_programming_paradigms)
```

My goal is to make a perfect function of this, so it follows the perfect paradigm. How can I optimize it, to be as perfect as it can. I'm very thankful about every answer to you guys!

Comment: In a bit of delightful irony, your quiz on programming paradigms was itself tagged with the incorrect paradigm. This is procedural programming and not functional.

Answer (score 2):

"Perfect" is somewhat subjective, but there is simplification to be had here.

I don't think there's a lot of value in passing around function references as you do; the complexity doesn't warrant it. It also doesn't particularly warrant a "cleaner" separated from the input function.

Your use of set literals and set intersection is reasonable.

`report_result` can just be your `main`. Add the call to it from a `__main__` guard.

Prefer string interpolation over `.format()`.

Consider calling `.lower()` for more forgiving string matching.

### Suggested

```
from typing import Iterator, Iterable


def capture_inputs() -> Iterator[str]:
    line = input("What are valid programming paradigms? ")
    for answer in line.split(","):
        yield answer.strip().lower()


def count_valid(paradigms: Iterable[str]) -> int:
    valid_paradigms = {"imperative", "functional", "object-oriented", "logical", "declarative"}
    given_paradigms = set(paradigms)
    return len(valid_paradigms & given_paradigms)


def main() -> None:
    inputs = capture_inputs()
    n_valid = count_valid(inputs)
    if n_valid > 0:
        print(f"You found {n_valid} valid paradigms")
    else:
        print("You did not find any valid paradigm")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

An alternative counting expression that does not need to construct a second set could look like

```
    return sum(1 for paradigm in paradigms if paradigm in valid_paradigms)
```

I have a weak preference for the first form over this one.

Comment: `valid_paradigms` would be good as a "constant"